# Can you please explain how the below python (dict) code works?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

/*  sample2 refers sample, yet when I update sample with {}, sample2 still have old keys and values  */

```
sample={1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}
sample2=sample   #reference
sample3=sample.copy()   #using copy method
sample
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
sample2
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
sample3
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
sample.popitem()
(1, 'one')
sample
{2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
sample2
{2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
sample3
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
sample={}
sample2
{2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
```

/*why sample2 still has those values, though being an reference for sample.

Comment: Note, this has nothing to do wtih `dict` objects, this is how *everything* works in Python. Read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

`sample2` is **not** a reference to `sample`! It is a reference to the same **value** (the dictionary data structure in the memory) that also goes by the name/reference `sample`.

There is no way that in Python a name can refer to another name. Names refer to values. *Always*.

`sample={}` **re-assigns** the name `sample` to another value. `sample2` does not care about this.

Answer (score 0):

`sample2` is not a reference to `sample`, but a reference to the value that `sample` had. When you do `sample = {}`, the old value still exists, and `sample2` still references it, but `sample1` now references `{}` instead.